# unable to delete pdf created by using itext in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm creating a duplicate pdf by taking an input pdf by adding some pic to header. i'm able to create the result pdf successfully i.e., duplicate pdf, but after creating this pdf, while trying to delete the original one i'm facing exception saying - file is being used by another process. Am i missing something?

```
public File createDuplicatePDF(String originalFile, String uploadFolder) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    File signature = new File("C:\\WORK\\Signature.bmp");
    File duplicateFile = new File(uploadFolder+"asds.pdf");
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(duplicateFile.toPath()));
    Document duplicateDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(duplicateDocument, outputStream);
    duplicateDocument.open();
    String duplicatePdfMessage = "asd";
    PdfPTable duplicateHeaderTable = new PdfPTable(2);
    // Set table width
    duplicateHeaderTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
    // Set relative cell widths
    duplicateHeaderTable.setWidths(new int[]{3, 1});

    PdfPCell cell;

    Font font = new Font();
    font.setColor(BaseColor.BLACK);

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(duplicatePdfMessage, font);

    cell = new PdfPCell(paragraph);
    cell.setBorder(0);
    duplicateHeaderTable.addCell(cell);

    Image signatureImage = Image.getInstance(signature.getPath());
    signatureImage.scaleToFit(100F, 50F);

    cell = new PdfPCell(signatureImage);
    cell.setBorder(0);
    cell.setPaddingLeft(2);
    cell.setPaddingBottom(2);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    duplicateHeaderTable.addCell(cell);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(originalFile));
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {

        duplicateDocument.add(duplicateHeaderTable);

        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(page);
        image.scalePercent(85F);
        image.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
        image.setBorderWidth(3F);
        image.setBorderColor(new GrayColor(0.5F));
        image.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        duplicateDocument.add(image);

        if (i < reader.getNumberOfPages()) {
            duplicateDocument.newPage();
        }
    }
    reader.close();

    outputStream.flush();
    duplicateDocument.close();
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    outputStream.close();
    return duplicateFile;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not closing the input stream for your original file.

Comment: thanks @karsten, i have changed this line - PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(originalFile)); by storing stream in another variable and closing this stream at the end. appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might stem from not properly closing the PdfReader. Wrap the PdfReader instantiation and the loop in a try-finally block to ensure closing, even in case of an exception:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(originalFile));
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        // Your code for page processing...
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

Additionally, ensure that you're correctly closing other resources such as duplicateDocument, writer, and outputStream.